# Pandas Big DataFrame Comparison

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I compare record from 2 big Dataframe consist 3 columns (X,Y,Z) and create a Result DataFrame recording paired data where both X's and Y's are close each other (<0.05)
It works for small amount of data, unfortunately I have around 33,000-35,000 rows make loop literally endless. Is there any other way to make loop faster ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=35000
DF1=pd.DataFrame({'X1': np.random.randn(n),'Y1': np.random.randn(n),'Z1': np.random.randn(n)})
DF2=pd.DataFrame({'X2': np.random.randn(n),'Y2': np.random.randn(n),'Z2': np.random.randn(n)})

Result=pd.DataFrame(columns=['X1','Y1','Z1','X2','Y2','Z2'])

i=0
for j in DF1.index:
    for k in DF2.index:
        if abs(DF1.X1[j]-DF2.X2[k])<0.05:
            if abs(DF1.Y1[j]-DF2.Y2[k])<0.05:
                Result.loc[i]=[DF1.X1[j]]+[DF1.Y1[j]]+[DF1.Z1[j]]+[DF2.X2[k]]+[DF2.Y2[k]]+[DF2.Z2[k]]
                i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this by slicing the DataFrame into 100 smaller portion based on X range value and only compare data within each portion, I don't want to loose any data in between portion so I give 5% overlap in between range and on the top and I will deal with duplication later.

It still very slow but at least I got the result, any faster alternative are welcom

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def Compare(DF1,DF2):
    Output=pd.DataFrame(columns=['X1','Y1','Z1','X2','Y2','Z2'])
    i=0
    for j in DF1.index:
        for k in DF2.index:
            if abs(DF1.X1[j]-DF2.X2[k])<0.05:
                if abs(DF1.Y1[j]-DF2.Y2[k])<0.05:
                    Output.loc[i]=[DF1.X1[j]]+[DF1.Y1[j]]+[DF1.Z1[j]]+[DF2.X2[k]]+[DF2.Y2[k]]+[DF2.Z2[k]]
                   i+=1
    return(Output)

n=35000
DF1=pd.DataFrame({'X1': np.random.randn(n),'Y1': np.random.randn(n),'Z1': 
np.random.randn(n)})
DF2=pd.DataFrame({'X2': np.random.randn(n),'Y2': np.random.randn(n),'Z2': 
np.random.randn(n)})

m=int(n/100)
start=DF1.X1.min()
stop=DF1.X1.max()*1.05
step=(DF1.X1.max()-DF1.X1.min())/m
arange=np.arange(start,stop,step)

Comparison=pd.DataFrame(columns=['X1','Y1','Z1','X2','Y2','Z2'])

for i in range(0,m-1):
    Input1=DF1[(DF1.X1>arange[i]) & (DF1.X1<(arange[i+1]-step/20))]
    Input2=DF2[(DF2.X2>arange[i]) & (DF2.X2<(arange[i+1]-step/20))]
    Comparison=Comparison.append(Compare(Input1,Input2))
```